# Community Wiki Answer to Removing Indexed Links

Tags: discussion, community-wiki

For just about half of the questions I answer on Pro Webmasters, all I could do is copy and paste the majority of this answer and rephrase it to fit the question:

> Sadly, you are taking all of the steps with the removal process. Google Webmasters also explains this issue with [their YouTube video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=H5UJVgO2v1E). It takes a good while for the actual removal process from all of Google and the search engine. Try to be patient now, and it will happen.
>
> Also, you have to remember, Google is indexing, re-indexing, and deleting records from their Search Engine all of the time at a massive rate already, but there is trillions upon trillions of sites that this needs to be done to and more links for indexing.

Should we globalize the answer into a Community Wiki to make it easier for myself and others?

Comment: If the same question is being asked, or the same answer would answer the question, then maybe it should be closed as a duplicate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pick the *best* incarnation of the question you can find, give it some editorial love and create a truly canonical post out of it. This means:

- Editing for brevity wherever possible
- Formatting / grammar touch-ups as needed
- Consolidating answers into one *really* good answer, if appropriate (you don't want a thesis, but if 5 answers result in 3 paragraphs, great!)
- Linking to the canonical question / answer in relevant tag wikis

.. you then have a great, easy to find canonical post that you can mark other questions of the same premise, just asked differently, as a duplicate of. The remaning 'stubs' will be there to guide folks to the canonical version of the post.

You might need to involve mods to merge a couple of the better similar questions into one, clean up duplicate info, etc - so feel free to flag if needed.

This is definitely one of those times where you should be seeking out a canonical, well-maintained version of the question along with a well-groomed answer just to have for folks that need it.